# Django: Using Third party app as a django app

Tags: django, django-south

Earlier i was using a [django-taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) app from the virtual environment. Now i need to add a 
custom field foreign Key(`Profile`) to model `Tag` of taggit app.
I moved the taggit app from virtual env to apps directory  and cross check the path of the that app:

```
<module 'taggit' from '/home/user/VIR/poll/taggit/__init__.pyc'>
```

Tagging seems to be working fine at that point.

in `Tag` model made following changes:

```
from profile.models import Profile

class Tag(TagBase):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")
```

while running the `schemamigration` i'm getting error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Profile
```

Any Insight to issue ?

Comment: Would urge you not to change a 3rd party module directly. One thing you could do is, create a new module, and extend the `Tag` model as `CustomTag` or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you use `Tag` inside `profile.models` and for that reason there is circular import and Python can handle it.

If you want to prevent circular import problems you can remove the `from profile.models import Profile` and use lazy model definition of foreign key:

```
class Tag(TagBase):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('profile.Profile')
```

I don't know the details in your situation but I think that you use **django-taggit** incorrectly. By default Tags use generic foreign key and you don't need explicit foreign key to point to your model http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html.

Comment: yes GFK is used by TaggedItem... but my case it seems appropriate to make that change.